# How do you read inner element values in a div according to main div?

Tags: jquery

I want to read each value of `select and textarea elements` in every div(refer0 and refer1) according to `MainContainer` div. the `refer0 and refer1` will create dynamically runtime and I don't know their ids. but `MainContainer div element` is static.

```
  <div id="MainContainer">

    <div id="Rfer0">
    <select id="LstRefer0" >
    <option value="52">a</option>
    <option value="116">b</option>
    </select>
    <textarea class="textbox" id="Area0" readonly="readonly" cols="20" rows="2" ></textarea>
    </div>

    <div id="Rfer1">
    <select id="LstRefer1" >
    <option value="52">a</option>
    <option value="116">b</option>
    </select>
    <textarea class="textbox" id="Area1" readonly="readonly" cols="20" rows="2" ></textarea>
    </div>


    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am on my iPad right now so I can't test the code but it should be something along these lines assuming you are using jquery

```
$('option').each(function() {
   alert( $(this).val() );
});

$('textarea').each(function() {
   alert( $(this).val() );
});
```